# Does dictionary, json (dumps, loads), defaultdict preserve the order from python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I always thought that dictionaries are un-ordered, that means we had to use something like OrderedDict for making it remember the insertion order.

When I saw the python docs it was mentioned that from python 3.7 dict is ordered.

I have few doubts w.r.t to this,

1. If dict preserve the insertion order does that mean even the `defaultdict` in collections will also do the same?
2. What about json.dumps and json.loads functionalities with defaultdict data, if I have a data like below,

> EDIT: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html  (json
> documentation)
>
> > Prior to Python 3.7, dict was not guaranteed to be ordered, so inputs
> > and outputs were typically scrambled unless collections.OrderedDict
> > was specifically requested. Starting with Python 3.7, the regular dict
> > became order preserving, so it is no longer necessary to specify
> > collections.OrderedDict for JSON generation and parsing.
>
> As far as the second doubt goes, I found above statement in python
> json docs but I wanted to know whether this will be applicable for
> nested defaultdict data.

```
# example defaultdict data for 2 doubt. 

from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(dict)

data["0"]["a"] = "Google"
data["0"]["b"] = "Google"
data["0"]["c"] = "Google"
data["1"]["a"] = "Google"
data["1"]["b"] = "Google"
data["1"]["c"] = "Google"
data["2"]["a"] = "Google"
data["2"]["b"] = "Google"
data["2"]["c"] = "Google"
data["3"]["c"] = "Google"
data["3"]["b"] = "Google"
data["3"]["a"] = "Google"

json.dumps(data) # will these operations preserve the order 
json.loads(data)
```

I have tried these and it was preserving order, but I wanted to be sure that this will always preserve order regardless.

Comment: Wouldn't it have been way easier just to try this?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @TimRoberts I tried it, it was keeping the order but I just wanted to be really sure. It was for a application I was building which will go to production. So I thought someone would help out.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I tried it it was keeping the order but I was absolute guarantee that it would always work. So that's why I thought someone in the community might shed some light on this.

Comment: The documentation says " defaultdict is a subclass of the built-in dict class. It overrides one method and adds one writable instance variable. The remaining functionality is the same as for the dict class and is not documented here."

Comment: @ThierryLathuille So that would mean it will keep the order right? even for nested nested dicts? And does json dumps and loads also preserve the order even for nested defaultdicts?

Comment: The defaultdict thing and the JSON thing are entirely separate issues - they belong in two questions.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Actually I had a particular use-case where I need to know for sure whether the json dump of  defaultdict data and later load it preserve the order? I couldn't find anything about this anywhere. Hopefully someone can provide some clarify on this.

Comment: JSON format doesn't support ordering in objects https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: @frost-nzcr4 But here in the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html  , they mentioned that `Prior to Python 3.7, dict was not guaranteed to be ordered, so inputs and outputs were typically scrambled unless collections.OrderedDict was specifically requested. Starting with Python 3.7, the regular dict became order preserving, so it is no longer necessary to specify collections.OrderedDict for JSON generation and parsing. ` but I wanted to know whether that would be applicable for defaultdict data and also wanted to know this works on nested dicts

Comment: You need to write some test cases that check if the encoding / decoding order remains the same, because any language can evolve. And Python X.Y might drop this functionality someday. Or choose another storage format.

Comment: @user_12 `defaultdict` will be ordered, it *is a `dict`*. But I personally would not rely on ordering in JSON, because I am pretty sure that isn't part of the standard, regardless of what the standard library `json` module decides to do. Why not use a JSON array instead of a JSON object?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am not sure what you meant by json array can you elaborate a bit? I need dict for data like in the example I have given and I write this data to sql table. Coming to `I personally would not rely on ordering in JSON`, can you provide why will this be a problem since python docs for json stated that it will work wont it? Sorry for asking too many question in a comment, I'm bit confused wanted some clarity

Comment: Because JSON object are unordered according to the JSON standard, if you want order, use a JSON array

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga okay got it, can you elaborate a bit on how to use JSON array, is it like just creating a empty list and adding dictionaries into it and use json dumps?

Comment: A python dict is serialized to a JSON object, a python list is serialized to a JSON array. This is pretty basic terminology you should familiarize yourself with: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Python dicts

Since python 3.7 the implementation of dict is ordered as a part of [the](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html) [specification](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html), not as a side effect of the implementation, so it can be used reliably. OrderedDict is still useful for several reasons:

- backward compatibility (if you need to support older python versions)
- reorder keys with [move_to_end](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.move_to_end) and [pop_item](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.popitem)
- clearer intent: if you rely on you dict keys being ordered, an OrderedDict makes it evident, but you do lose some performance
- the order of the keys is considered when comparing OrderedDicts, and ignored for dicts (thanks to @ShadowRanger for the notice):

For example:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

one_dict = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
another_dict = {"b": 2, "a": 1}

one_ordered_dict = OrderedDict(a=1, b=2)
another_ordered_dict = OrderedDict(b=2, a=1)

print(one_dict == another_dict)
# True
print(one_ordered_dict == another_ordered_dict)
# False
```

If any of those requirements are needed, OrderedDict can help you, else you can just use a regular dict.

#### Json dump/load

Regarding the `json.dump`, this is a different question:

As far as I can tell, the [`JSONEncoder`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/51a85ddce8b336addcb61b96f04c9c5edef07296/Lib/json/encoder.py#L333) iterates
over the [keys](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/51a85ddce8b336addcb61b96f04c9c5edef07296/Lib/json/encoder.py#L356), so it should not change the order.

You can force a lexicographic ordering if you want:

```
>>> json.dumps({'b': 1, 'a': 2}, sort_keys=True)
'{"a": 2, "b": 1}'
```

Regarding the loading, I don't see why the order would not be preserved, but I admit I'm getting lost in the source code for the [decoder](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/51a85ddce8b336addcb61b96f04c9c5edef07296/Lib/json/decoder.py) and [scanner](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/51a85ddce8b336addcb61b96f04c9c5edef07296/Lib/json/scanner.py).

If you want, you can use:

```
>>> json.loads('{"b": 2, "a": 1}', object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
OrderedDict([('b', 2), ('a', 1)])
```

#### Nested dicts

The above applies for nested dicts as well: `_iterencode_dict` is called [recursively](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/51a85ddce8b336addcb61b96f04c9c5edef07296/Lib/json/encoder.py#L401), and the keys are [sorted](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/51a85ddce8b336addcb61b96f04c9c5edef07296/Lib/json/encoder.py#L352) for all dicts.

Indeed:

```
>>> json.dumps({'b': 1, 'a': {'d': 1, 'c': 3}}, sort_keys=True)
'{"a": {"c": 3, "d": 1}, "b": 1}'
```

Cheers!

Comment: `Json.dumps` **sort_keys** will work only if we have a dict isn't it? In my case I have nested dict so this won't work right? Since sort_keys only sorts the outer keys. If you see the example data I have provided above, that is the type of data I have

Comment: @user_12 no it *sorts the keys of all the JSON objects*

Comment: I have added a section regarding nested dicts, it will sort keys recursively.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Got it, then I can safely use sort_keys whenever I use dump or load. That is helpful

Comment: Additional (possible) advantage to `OrderedDict` over ordered plain `dict`: `OrderedDict`'s equality tests, when comparing to another `OrderedDict`, are order-sensitive. `dict` is not (`dict == dict` or `dict == OrderedDict` or `OrderedDict == dict` is order-insensitive, but `OrderedDict == OrderedDict` is order-sensitive; if the key order doesn't match, it won't be equal).

Comment: @user_12 you can only use `sort_keys` when dumping. @ShadowRanger I will add an example for that, thank you.

Comment: @Pietro when I use ``object_pairs_hook``, will it read the data in exact format that is present? Is this consistent behaviour regardless of nested dicts

Comment: @user_12 if you mean it will preserve the order then yes.